# Process 'storeagent' eating bandwidth

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

Recently I noticed a hike in my daily internet usage. After investigation I came to know that a process called `storeagent` was downloading huge amounts of data from the internet. When googled I found that it's related to app store.

1. How can I prevent `storeagent` from downloading data?
2. If I do so will it prevent updates for my applications?
3. Will it make any security issue?

Comment: Is it possibly downloading something like Mavericks, that file is 5 Gig in size :)

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.9.2. I think it's Mavericks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try turning off the automated download of updates.

- Launch the **System Preferences**
- Go to the **App Store** preferences pane
- Uncheck **Download available updates in the background**